# Installed packages that do not run in Python (VS code)

Tags: python, visual-studio, scikit-learn

I am using python in VS code. When I check my installed packages, I can see both sklearn ( the version is 0 though) and scikit-learn. However, when I am trying to import datasets from sklearn, I receive the message:" ImportError: No module named sklearn". I should also mention that I have used the same Python path and VS  code environment to run sklearn about 3 months ago and at that time it ran without any problem!
Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: this problem was many times on Stackoverflow. Today I saw already similar question.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to your **Python Interpreter Configuration**. Check your Visual Studio Code's python interpreter.

**First**. Open the Command Palette (**Windows**: `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`, **macOS**: `cmd` + `shift` + `p`)

**Second**. Type `Python: Select Interpreter` on the palette

**Third**. If you've checked your python interpreter, then check your terminal's python version by running following command. (Because you might have run commands like `$ pip install SOME_PACKAGE` in your terminal.)

```sh
$ python3 --version
```

If those are matching, install `sklearn` package again with `$ pip install sklearn`. And then try again.

---

I recommend you to use Python version management tool, `Pyenv`. Check https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv for `pyenv`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I followed your instruction and received this in my terminal:                                                                                                                  
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in /../.../miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.0)
Requirement already satisfied:.......................................                                                                  My understanding is that sklearn has already been installed but still I receive the same error when I try to run my code.

Comment: @Bahar If all set correctly, try `$ python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then `$ pip3 install -U scikit-learn scipy numpy matplotlib`